# Pandas datareader installation failed

Tags: python, pandas, datareader

I tried to install pandas datareader through Anaconda promt, but I got this error message. What could be the problem?

I use Windows 7 and Ancaonda 1.6.9

[image: Error message]

Thanks in advance,
Roland

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please copy and paste the error message. Do not attach images.

Comment: works for me, are you trying to do this in an office or personal network?

Comment: It seems like something is wrong with your network connection. Is the issue related to the `pandas-datareader` alone?

Comment: try this `pip install pandas-datareader --trusted-host pypi.python.org`

Comment: Yesterday I tried to install via personal network, but today I tried again in the office, The error message the same

Comment: Is it possible to install somehow in offline mode?

Answer (score 0):

There are two additional methods to install:

`pip install pandas-datareader`

or the latest devleopment version:

`git clone https://github.com/pydata/panda-datareader
cd pandas-datareader
python setup.py install .`